# Why is the torque around axis 1 zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotation

> Consider a uniform cylindrical rod mounted on a horizontal frictionless axle through its 
>   center. The axle is carried on a turntable revolving with constant angular velocity Ω, with the 
>   center of the rod over the axis of the turntable. Let θ be the angle the rod makes with horizontal 
>   as shown in the sketch. Use Euler’s equations to find θ as a function of time. Assume θ is small.

[image]
[image]

So I wrote Euler's equation of motion. After that it is assumed that torque is 0 of axis 1. I can't understand the concept why is this happening. According to me it should be non zero as theta is coming out to be harmonic so torque being zero shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: These are just practice questions. Extra questions given to some students for extra practice. I can't really understand the reason for the torque being zero around axis 1.

Comment: The guidelines apply regardless of the origin of the question: it's irrelevant whether they're self-study, practice questions given to you by your instructor, or formal homework. Please read the guidelines carefully. As it stands, this question is likely to be put on hold until it's edited to conform to those guidelines.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please tell me if it's according to the guidelines?

Comment: Please clarify the *conceptual* difficulty you're having with the question. Why do you think the torque should/should not be zero around axis one? Once you specify that in your question, it'll be on-topic for Physics SE.

Comment: Added the reason why I think torque should be non zero. But is given as zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torque is only proportional to the angular acceleration in an inertial reference frame.  In a rotating frame, one has that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf L + \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf L = \mathbf M$$

$$\implies \frac{d}{dt}\mathbf L = I \dot{\boldsymbol \omega} = \mathbf M - \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf L $$

In such a frame, $\mathbf M=0$ does not imply that $\dot{\boldsymbol \omega}=0$, so your argument

> theta is coming out to be harmonic so torque being zero shouldn't be possible

is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

So torque is defined as the cross product of r with F, where r is the distance from the axis of rotation where the force is applied and F of course is the force. Here, r=0, because the axis 1 passes through the horizontal axes which are applying the force on the rod. Hence, torque about axis 1 is zero.

Comment: But theta comes out to be harmonic. Also can you specify which forces are you talking about?

Comment: @Kaneki I am talking about the force that is applied to the cylindrical rod via the horizontal axle that passes through the rod's center, and hence through the axis 1.